# Contact app with selective sync?

Tags: contacts, sync, google

I am using a Xiaomi Mi5 and the default Contact app sync ALL contacts with Google which creates a huge redundant list of any person I ever emailed. There is no option to select which Group/Folder to sync.

I thought I would find a better Contacts app that sync only the 'My Contacts' folder from Google to my Phone to alleviate this issue but that's a very specific criteria and I'm not sure how to look it up.

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: Another contacts app won't help you, as it's not the contacts app that does the sync but Google's "contacts sync adapter". Ugly work-around: store contacts you don't wish to sync into a separate contacts-book (the "local" one, also called "phone", if your device supports that) – basically chose anything but not the Google contacts for them.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the App Contacts+ from Play store which, eventhough it has ads which are a bit annyoing, did allow me to select the 'sources' of contacts from both my personal and professional Google accounts.
You can research articles on the best Android contacts apps, in my case this one suited me. Still have my eyes open for a better solution though...